# Does beer need to be Yashan

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, liquor-beer, yoreh-deah, yashan-chadash

According to Halacha, is one allowed to drink beer made with Chadash grain (does beer need to be Yashan)? Let’s assume for example this is from a Jewish farmer in Israel and you know it was planted at a point which would make it Chadash, theoretically would it just be a prohibition on eating it as bread and would it be permissible to drink it as beer or no?

Comment: It's definitely not just bread. It's לחם וקלי וכרמל

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be prohibited. The  Shach Y”D 293:6 says
ע"כ ובס' לח"מ סוף מסכת תרומות האריך למצוא היתר
על שכר שעורים הנעשה מחדש מטעם שהמשקה היוצא מהן מותר
וצריך להתיישב בדבר כי מתשובת הרא"ש ריש כלל ב' ומתרומות
הדשן הנ"ל ומשאר פוסקים משמע שאסור
loosely translated the above is trying to find a leniency  for those who drink beer from chodosh but the conclusion is that is difficult to find one.

The argument behind the leniency is that  the liquid derivate of the grain is not what the Torah prohibited as Chodosh. There is further discussion in the Poskim but the general consensus is that beer or other liquid would be like any other Chodosh and prohibited .

Comment: For context, the general consensus is that all chodosh is prohibited but the general practice was to not care. Back then the main chodosh crop was barley and hence the main problematic food was beer. All the discussion about finding ways to permit chodosh is focused on beer since people (apparently) couldn't live without beer. Hence while this is true that the shach is a difficult leniency, that doesn't make it not mainstream (for certain definitions of mainstream)

Comment: @doubleAA to what extent is/was this specific heter accepted - ie of not eating chadash bread but being OK with beer?